# Why is it okay to create this shared lib without -l flags for dependencies?

Tags: c, linker, dependencies, shared-libraries, linker-flags

The rules regarding linking are getting jumbled in my head.

I have this little C file that I want to turn into a shared library. For the purpose of illustration, I'm calling a `libuv` function, but it could just as well have been calling a function from any library.

```
// func.c
#include <uv.h>

int func(void) {
  uv_close(NULL, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

I compile it to a shared library, like so; note that I do not link with `libuv` by providing a `-luv` flag to `cc`:

```
$ cc -fpic -g -c func.c
$ cc -shared -o libfunc.so func.o
$ ldd ./libfunc.so
        statically linked
$
```

I don't understand what that "statically linked" output actually means -- I thought I'd created a shared lib (not a static lib) by specifying the `-shared` flag?

Anyhow, trying to make sense of things, I next tried creating my shared lib explicitly linking `libuv`:

```
$ cc -fpic -g -c func.c
$ cc -shared -o libfunc.so func.o -luv
$ ldd ./libfunc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe2b39a000)
        libuv.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1 (0x00007f012d6d0000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f012d4a7000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f012d710000)
$
```

**Can someone please explain what is happening between the two different "methods" of creating the `libfunc.so` shared library?** Why did adding `-luv` to the `cc` flags result in those dependencies being created/recognized by `ldd`? Also: why did the first version (without `-luv`) even work? I thought the fact that I was using a function from another library *obliged me* to provide a correct `-l` argument during linking, meaning I thought the attempt at creating the shared library *without* specifying `-luv` would have failed(?)

---

Update: Following up on @JohnBollinger's comment, I repeated the `-fpic` flag for the link command, but it doesn't appear to have affected the observed behavior:

```
$ cc -fpic -g -c func.c
$ cc -fpic -shared -o libfunc.so func.o
$ ldd ./libfunc.so
        statically linked
$
```

```
$ cc -fpic -g -c func.c
$ cc -fpic -shared -o libfunc.so func.o -luv
$ ldd ./libfunc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff043f0000)
        libuv.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1 (0x00007fea17963000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fea1773a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fea179a3000)
$
```

---

Update: my `gcc`/`cc` and `ld` versions:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ cc --version
cc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
$
```

---

My Linux distro, fwiw, which is Ubuntu WSL, release jammy:

```
$ uname -a
Linux US193F98B0DB51 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
```

I *assumed* the fact that I was running WSL was irrelevant, but the fact that @JohnBollinger cannot reproduce my result in RHEL/Centos 8 has me uncertain about everything. I do not have access to a physical Linux box to compare behavior there.

---

Following up on @DarkSoda's inquiry, it appears that both versions of `libfunc.so` (with and without `-luv` during linking) are the same size:

```
$ cc -fpic -g -c func.c
$ cc -fpic -shared -o libfunc.so func.o
$ ls -l ./libfunc.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 20528 Jan 11 18:53 ./libfunc.so
$
$
$ rm -f ./func.o ./libfunc.so
$
$ cc -fpic -g -c func.c
$ cc -fpic -shared -o libfunc.so func.o -luv
$ ls -l ./libfunc.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 20528 Jan 11 18:53 ./libfunc.so
$
```

Comment: I don't think it explains your observations, but you ought to repeat (almost) all your compile options in your link command.  The `-fpic` option in particular.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - noted, and I updated the post accordingly, but fwiw, the reason I left out `-fpic` in the link command was because that was the pattern followed here: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html

Comment: Which shows that you need to be careful about accepting things you read at face value.  I'd consider the GCC manual more authoritative, and its documentation of the `-shared` option says: "For predictable results, you must also specify the same set of options used for compilation (-fpic, -fPIC, or model suboptions) when you specify this linker option."

Comment: I do not reproduce the results you describe.  With the `-shared` option, I get dynamically linked libraries whether I link with `-luv` or not (and also, independently, whether I link with `-fpic` or not).  This is with GNU ld version 2.32, as built for RHEL / CentOS 8.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - this is damn curious. I updated my post with my `gcc` and `ld` versions. Note: I'm not actually sure that the first version (where it says "statically linked") _is actually a static library_ -- I'd be damned surprised if it was. I think it's possibly that I'm not understanding what the output is actually saying. OTOH, I don't know how to reconcile my observation with the fact that you can't reproduce them. Our versions are not that far apart. (I'm assuming/half-remembering that `cc` invokes `ld` under the hood)

Comment: There is a difference between a statically linked ELF object and a static library.  `ldd`'s output indicates that in the your first case, you have the former.  (Compare to its output when you use `ar` to build a *bona fide* static library containing the same object file.)

Comment: I'm inclined to guess that you have an unusual or wrong configuration of either GCC or LD, or perhaps that your version of one of these that has a genuine bug.

Comment: I do not expect WSL to make a difference, but I cannot absolutely rule it out.  More likely is that the behavior is specific to your particular Ubuntu builds of GCC and LD.  Or, again, that there's a genuine bug loose in your particular versions of these.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - maybe the answer lies in this idea of a "statically linked ELF object" that you described -- can you speak a bit more on that (or can you point me to accurate reading material on it)? The phrase "statically linked" when talking about _shared libraries_ is screwing with my brain. :P

Comment: @JohnBollinger - "you have an unusual or wrong configuration of either GCC or LD" -- not sure if this is veering off-topic, or if this is actually getting to the heart of the problem described in this post, but I wish there was some way I could identify if there was a bug or wrong configuration. What I can say is that this is a fresh install of Ubuntu WSL, straight out of the Microsoft Store: I frequently tear-down (unregister) and recreate Ubuntu WSL instances, so I'm _fairly_ certain there is no bad configuration (persistent or otherwise) in my environment where I'm running `cc` (or `ld`).

Comment: I'm not supposing that *you* are likely to have configured it oddly.  I am suggesting that whoever packaged it for Ubuntu may have done so.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - I'll leave this question open for now, in case a definitive answer comes through. In the meanwhile, I'll see if I can get a hold of a physical Linux PC (with a different release of Ubuntu?), and compare the result of running the same experiment there. If there is a difference, maybe along the lines of your observation on RHEL/CentOS, perhaps that would warrant a separate, specific question. I'm grateful for your help and tenacity trying to get to the heart of this problem with me.

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in comments, I do not reproduce the behavior you describe, but it turns out that I can obtain a similar result by adding option `-nostdlib` to the link command:

```
cc -shared -nostdlib -o libfunc.so func.o
```

The result is an ELF shared object that `ldd` reports as "statically linked".  Using `readelf -a` to examine the two files produced with and without `-nostdlib` shows that both are *bona fide* ELF shared objects (so not "static libraries", which have an altogether different form).  There is a variety of differences between them, however, starting with the fact that the statically linked one's dynamic section does not contain a `NEEDED` entry referring to libc.so.6 (nor any other `NEEDED` entries).  This one is also missing other entries in its dynamic section,has considerably fewer sections overall, and has half as many entries in its symbol table.

Some of that is likely related to not including Glibc startup files in the link, but some is related simply to **not dynamically linking to any other shared libraries**, and in particular, not to libc.  This is what makes it "statically linked", even though it itself is a shared library.  And given that the contents do not (directly) call any standard library functions or access any external objects provided by the standard library, that's not such an unreasonable result, even if it's not what my version of the toolchain produces by default.

> Why did adding `-luv` to the cc flags result in those dependencies being created/recognized by ldd?

Adding `-luv` to the link command instructs the linker that the shared library should be linked against libuv.  That will be via *dynamic* linking by default if a shared-library version is found.  If linking is successful then the result is necessarily dynamically linked to libuv, whether or not it is (dynamically) linked to libc.

> why did the first version (without -luv) even work? I thought the fact that I was using a function from another library obliged me to provide a correct -l argument during linking, meaning I thought the attempt at creating the shared library without specifying -luv would have failed(?)

This is a difference between linking a shared library and linking an executable.  And even so, not all shared library systems support it.  The resulting shared lib has an undefined symbol `uv_close` that is not resolved by any shared library dynamically linked to it.  But at least with ELF and Linux's dynamic linker, that symbol can still be resolved at runtime from another shared object included in the dynamic link (by virtue of being dynamically linked to a different shared object, such as the main executable, or being manually loaded).

On some platforms you would indeed be obligated to include `-luv` to ensure that all symbols could be resolved.  On Linux, that's still almost always what you want, but it's not *required*.

---

In the end, it makes a certain amount of sense to avoid dynamically linking to libc when that doesn't resolve any symbols or otherwise provide anything useful to the library.  That's a pretty unusual situation, but it applies to your example, and that is the threshold consideration that allows the result that surprised you.

I guess you also did not appreciate the difference between a static library (a simple archive of object files) and a statically-*linked* shared library (a coherent shared object that does not depend on any other dynamically-linked libraries).